# Unable to connect to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

This is my php code below. For some reason, when I want it to connect to the database, it says "No database selected" but when I do a connection test it says "Success in database connection!" So there's an error in the code below. Also I think it may be interfering with my form so I must have a typo; when I remove the PHP the forms runs normally, but I want it to connect to the database.

```
<?php
// let's initialize vars to be printed to page in the HTML section so our script does not return errors 
// they must be initialized in some server environments, not shown in video
$errorMsg = "";
$First_Name = "";
$Last_Name = "";
$Email = "";
$Password = "";


// This code runs only if the form submit button is pressed
if (isset ($_POST['firstname'])){

    /* Example of cleaning variables in a loop
    $vars = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
       $vars .= "$key = $value<br />";
    }
    print "$vars";
    exit();
    */
     $First_Name = $_POST['firstname'];
     $Last_Name = $_POST['lastname'];
     $Email = $_POST['email'];
     $Password = $_POST['password'];

     // Connect to database
     include "connect_to_mysql.php";
     $emailCHecker = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
     $emailCHecker = eregi_replace("`", "", $EmailCHecker);
     // Database duplicate e-mail check setup for use below in the error handling if else conditionals
     $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='$emailCHecker'");
     $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 

}

     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, password, sign_up_date) 
     VALUES('$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Email','$Password', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());

     $id = mysql_insert_id();

     // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)        
     mkdir("members/$id", 0755);    

?>
```

This is my form coding below

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
    <td width="23%" class="right">First Name:</td>
    <td width="77%" class="left left_nowrap"><input type="text" class="left left_nowrap tb10" id="First_Name" value="<?php print "$First_Name"; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Last Name:</td>
    <td class="left left_nowrap"><input type="text" class="left left_nowrap tb10" id="Last_Name"  value="<?php print "$Last_Name"; ?>" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Email:</td>
    <td class="left left_nowrap"><input type="text" class="left left_nowrap tb10" id="Email" value="<?php print "$Email";?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Password:</td>
    <td class="left left_nowrap"><input type="password" class="left left_nowrap tb10" id="Password"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td class="left left_nowrap"><input type="password" class="left left_nowrap tb10" id="Confirm_Password"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Gender:</td>
    <td class="left left_nowrap"><span class="right">
      <select name="Gender" class="large tb10" id="Gender" value="<?php print "$gender"; ?>">
        <option value="Please Select...">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="submit" class="submit tb10" value="Sign-UP" /></td>
  </tr>     
    </form>
```

connect_to_mysql.php

```
 <?php 

/* 
1: "die()" will exit the script and show an error statement if something goes wrong with the "connect" or "select" functions. 
2: A "mysql_connect()" error usually means your username/password are wrong 
3: A "mysql_select_db()" error usually means the database does not exist.
*/
// Place db host name. Sometimes "localhost" but 
// sometimes looks like this: >>      ???mysql??.someserver.net
$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "Shayaa"; 
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "nestle324"; 
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "social_media";

// Run the actual connection here 
$con = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db('social_media', $con ) or die ("no database");         
?>
```

Comment: eregi_replace() is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php ....STOP using mysql_insert_id as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: ...And this is throwing "cannot connect to database?"

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The problem is probably in connect_to_mysql.php - I don't see test connection, is test specifying which db on connect and connect_to_mysql missing db to connect to?

Comment: Can you post your **connect_to_mysql.php script**. Because if you are getting an error like no database selected then the bug must be in your connection script.

Comment: <?php 


// Place db host name. Sometimes "localhost" but 
// sometimes looks like this: >>      ???mysql??.someserver.net
$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "Shayaa"; 
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "nestle324"; 
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "social_media";

// Run the actual connection here 
$con = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db('social_media', $con ) or die ("no database");         
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use mysqli or PDO
- look if you are selecting databse while you are getting no database selected `$sql = mysql_select_db('your database name', $connection)`
- `stristr` achieves exactly the same result as `eregi_replace` (at least when you don't use regular expressions):

EDIT:

```
         $sql= "INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, password,bio_body, sign_up_date , account_type) 
 VALUES(  '".$_SESSION['firstname']."','".$_SESSION['lastname']."','".$_SESSION['email']."','".$_SESSION['password']."','NULL' ,NOW() , 'a' ) " ; 

 if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL server can handle many databases. At a minimum you'll have the `mysql` database itself, which holds server specific data like user accounts and your own application database.

So simply connecting to the server is not enough for any query related to a database. You have to select a database.

in your case, without modifying the rest of the code and MySQL API you need to utilize this command before you can submit a query

```
mysql_select_db( 'your database name', $dbConnection );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Using PHP's MySQL extension is not recommended, since this is going to be removed in future PHP versions. See the link above for alternatives

Comment: This should go into your connect_to_mysql.php, try by yourself, it's not that hard :)